# Find shortest path by color

Tags: algorithms

Let G(V, E) be a directed graph (non circular graph with no weights on edges) with Blue, Yellow and Green colored vertices.
I need to find an algorithm to travel among all blue vertices.

My way to solve it is:

1. Run DFS and count the number of red vertices.
   While  in the DFS ill be adding weight to the edges in that way:

Blue to Blue weight = 0.
Blue to Yellow/Green, weight = 1
Yellow/Green to Blue, weight = 1
Yellow/Green to Yellow/Green,  weight = 2

2. Run dijkstra and count every time I get to a red vector then break when the count is same as (1) counter.

In that way ill get the shortest path to get to all Blue vertices in the graph.

Time complexity is O(v log e + e + v)

Is that question makes any sense?
Thanks.

Comment: do you want to travel only among blue vertices? what do you mean by "Blue path"?

Comment: If the above comment is what you mean by "Blue path", can't you just take the subgraph induced by the Blue vertices and then use Dijkstra?

Comment: Yes, I need to travel only among blue vertices.

Comment: How would you solve this problems if there is no restriction to the blue vertices?

Comment: Hey friends, can you check if my answer makes sense? Appreciate it.

Comment: there are faster as dijstra algorithms standart for that is A* since you travel only blue vertices, do not concider weight of others, or concider it to be infinity

Comment: To clarify - do you mean “find any path that passes through all blue vertices,” “check whether there’s a path that passes through all blue vertices,” or “find the shortest path that passes through all blue vertices?”

Comment: Find the shortest path that passes through all blue vertices, sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 0):

Do a BFS on the subgraph consisting of only blue vertices. You don't need Dijkstra since there are no edge weights.

Comment: Hey, I think i cannot do it because there can be two blue vertices with no edge between them and you need to pass through Green/Yellow edges

Comment: not the best choise, heuristic based would be usually better then BFS

Comment: Hey! How would you improve my answer?